# how to configure naxsi for json rest apis?

Tags: php, security, nginx, firewall

for example one of my APIs is:
Post request:
/api/v0/login
body:

```
{
"username":"xxx@ggg.com",
"password":"eeeee"
}
```

I want to secure this API with naxsi, I could not find anywhere to config naxsi to accept json in body (it suppose these are sql injection code in body)

Answer (score 0):

I think that naxsi is blocking your mentioned request as it has '@' special character. Check the sql injection Mainrules defined in naxsi.core.rules file and Whitelist the rule (which is blocking this) to allow it to take '@' in request.